# Using "snakemake --config" to pass flags to a command

Tags: snakemake

I have read the Snakemake tutorial and it is clear to me how to use "snakemake --config ..." to modify parameters, and these get passed to the command being executed. Can I use "--config" to pass a flag to a command? For example, can I write a Snakefile that will execute either of these commands, based on using "--config"?

```
muscle -in unaligned.fa -out aligned.fa

muscle -in unaligned.fa -out aligned.fa -msf
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, from within a shell command definition in Snakemake, you can directly access config:

```
rule a:
    input: ...
    output: ...
    shell:
        "muscle -in {input} -out {output} {config[muscle-params]}"
```

Given that you e.g. invoke `snakemake --config muscle-params="-msf"`
or (even better) have the key defined in your config file.